# Relative quaternion rotation (delta rotation) produces unstable results

Tags: geometry, 3d, rotations, quaternions

*Disclaimer: I asked this question [here on game development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/143430/relative-quaternion-rotation-delta-rotation-produces-unstable-results) before.*

Use case: I have a `currentRotation` quaternion and a `targetRotation` quaternion and need to calculate the relative rotation between them - as in: what rotation do I need to apply to transform an object (in a 3D scene) with currentRotation so that it has targetRotation.

The standard solution seems to be to calculate the relative rotation *(1)* $q_{delta} = {q_{current}}^{-1}*q_{target}$ and then (later at some point) combine it with the object's current rotation *(2)* $q_{new} = q_{delta} * q_{current}$ to actually transform the object.

Combining these, I get the formula *(3)* $q_{new} = {q_{current}}^{-1}*q_{target}*q_{current}$ which makes sense for me - ultimatively, I set the object's new rotation to be the target rotation.

This method works well for **most** cases of current-target-rotations, but  unfortunately **not for all** - it is unstable and I don't understand why.

I created a [codepen example](https://codepen.io/codepenAtiX/pen/KqeYjN?editors=0011) that shows a problematic case. To be more precise, calculating the relative rotation from `(0°, 170°, 10°)` to `(0°, 170°, -10°)` which should be in my opinion `(0°, 0°, -20°)` (written as XYZ-euler angles for readability) fails - combining the original rotation with the delta rotation does not yield the expected target rotation, so $q_{target} \neq q_{new} = {q_{current}}^{-1}*q_{target}*q_{current}$ (see *(3)*)

To wrap up: I am looking for your help to understand...

1. My suspicion is that *(1)* produces incorrect delta rotations for some input values, so combining the rotations does not yield the correct result. Why?
2. If so, how can I recognize "problematic input values" and handle them gracefully?

Comment: Why are you writing $q_{delta} = q_{current}^{-1}q_{target}$? Shouldn't it be $q_{delta} = q_{target}q_{current}^{-1}$? That is, you have to undo the current rotation first before applying the target rotation?

Comment: Also a note --- your formula (3) *shouldn't* make sense. It literally says that $q_{new}$ is NOT $q_{target}$ (unless you get lucky and $q_{target}$ commutes with $q_{current}$).

Comment: (1) quaternion order: I guess it's similar to the combination of matrices that given the system (WebGL, threejs) I use, you define the combination order from right to left - but to be honest, that's just the way it worked out.
(2) regarding formula 3: Interesting! @Neal Care to explain in detail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think of quaternions as *actions, not states.* If I want to represent the *state* of an object's rotation by a quaternion, this must always be in reference to some unrotated state.

So when I see that the rotation of some object is represented by the quaternion $q_{current}$, I interpret it as "the object has been rotated away from its initial state by $q_{current}$."

If I want to reconfigure the object so it has rotation $q_{target}$, what I mean is, "I want to apply some rotation $q_{delta}$ to the object so that the result has been rotated from its initial state by $q_{new}$." When interpreted this way, we see that first we need to rotate back to the initial state, then to its new state:
$$ q_{delta} = q_{target}q_{current}^{-1} $$

Remember that functions act on the left! The quaternions are acting on the object, so the actions should be read right-to-left: first we do $q_{current}^{-1}$, then we do $q_{target}$. As you say in your comment above, this why matrix libraries often define combination order from right to left --- they're also often interpreted as acting on vectors.

Does this make sense? Let's check:
$$ q_{new} = q_{delta}q_{current} = q_{target}q_{current}^{-1}q_{current} = q_{target} $$
just as desired.

Note: Your (3) is *not* the same as the previous equation! In fact, *quaternions do not commute*, so the equation $q_{new} = q_{current}^{-1}q_{target}q_{current}^{-1}$ all but guarantees that $q_{new}$ will **not** be equal to $q_{target}$.